# itext white paper on digital signatures: page 68: two certificates can be very confusing to users

Tags: pdf, itext

0) I'm not sure if I'm reading the whitepaper correctly, there's a chapter on Certificate Authorities, so I assume that the white paper would teach me how to digitally sign a pdf.  But page 68 appears to only show that the document is signed but it doesn't do "certify documents" are authentic.

I'm reading page 68 of this article

http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures

I want to also comment that the two signatures can be a source of confusion to anyone looking at the pdf.  The first confusion MY end users will ask is:

a) why are there two certificates (I've read it and understand the reason why there's two certificates) where one says one thing but the other says another?

What's concerning is that Bruno Lowagie's certificate is marked as NOT trusted as a "sign documents or data" and pdf is NOT trusted for "Certify Documents" What I'm trying to say is, it's very confusing to **end users** when they click on the certificates and see that one is trusted and the other is not.  Figure 3.3 vs. 3.4. page 68.

The certificates are aligned as such:

```
Cert Signing Authority <supp
Bruno Lowagie <bruno@low
```

Conversely, someone sent me a sample of a pdf that has only ONE certificate, and it says "Certified by [HIS COMPANY NAME]" then when you click on Show Signer's Certificate, on the left column you'll see the following:

```
Adobe Root CA
    GlobalSign CA for Adobe
          HIS COMPANY NAME
```

Here, you click though any of the above levels Adobe Root CA, GlobalSign CA for Adobe, and HIS COMPANY NAME; they ALL say certificate is trusted to "sign documents or data, certify documents."  This consistency makes sense.

I have not played around with the code yet, but is it possible to use itext and make it look like what I see in my friend's sample pdf?

If I'm going to pay for the itext license, I want to make sure that I'm able to programmatically digitally sign the pdf with CA certificates and that the Trusts would ALL look consistent, which makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one certificate, you are confronted with a **self-signed** certificate. **Self-signed** certificates **should never be used to sign a document**. The only **self-signed** certificate that should be trusted is the **root certificate** of a Certificate Authority (e.g. the Adobe Root Certificate, the GlobalSign root certificate,...).

These certificates are kept in a vault under very high security. They are **NEVER** used to sign a document. They are used to issue intermediate certificates.

In your example, you mention the "Adobe Root CA". GlobalSign paid Adobe a lot of money for Adobe to use this certificate to issue the intermediate certificate "GlobalSign CA for Adobe". GlobalSign makes money using this certificate to issue certificates for companies who buy an HSM or a USB token (in case of a USB token, there's even one extra certificate in the certificate chain).

This is how it works. If you have read my whitepaper, you have missed the part where the concept of having a Certificate Authority (CA) is explained. If you would send me a signed document, and I would **NOT** see a certificate issued by a CA, I would **NOT** accept your document. I would **demand** that you either use a certificate under the Certified Document Services (CDS) with Adobe's certificate in the Root, or I would ask you to use a certificate of which the root certificate can be found in Adobe's Approved Trusted List (AATL).

If I would only see your company name in the certificate chain, I would **NOT** accept your document. Your allegation that I would be confused when I see Adobe's or GlobalSign's certificate is wrong. The opposite is true: I **need** to see a certificate from a CA before I can trust your signature.

Self-signed certificates will never *automatically* result in a green check mark. To get a green check mark automatically, you need a certificate that is issued by a CA. This CA should be a member of either CDS or AATL. This means that the certificate will need to meet or exceed FIPS 140-1 Level 2. This implies that you'll need to invest in either a Hardware Security Module (HSM) or a USB token.
You will not succeed in getting an automatically trusted "green check mark" signature using a software certificate (PKCS#12), not with iText, not with any other software.

HSM:

[image: Hardware Security Module]

USB Token:
[image: USB token]

Comment: Bruno, thanks for the time and explanation.  I'll complete your whitepaper then come back and check off this thread as the answer.  I tend to want absorb everything first. If I check it off now and have more questions later, for clarification, I'm not sure if you're allowed to add or edit your reply.

Comment: I should have finished your whitepaper before I asked the question.  Your whitepaper is very helpful!  Without your white paper, I have no idea where people would even begin to learn about this sort of stuff.  Thanks again.